# Apache mod_rewrite in loop

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have two kind of URL's:

1. http://www.mydomain.com/Admin/Cpanel
2. http://www.mydomain/Admin/shared/css/somestyle.css

1 is a command to index.php and 2 is an actual file

I need to mod_rewrite request 1 to /MyApp/index.php
I need to mod_rewrite request 2 to /MyApp/shared/css/somestyle.css

in `/` I'v got a `.htaccess` file with `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteCond ^MyApp/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^MyApp/([^/]*)/(.*)?$ /MyApp/$1/$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond ^MyApp/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /MyApp/index.php [L,QSA]
```

mod_rewrite seems to go in a loop.

I'm sure the answer is very simple, but I after one day . . . I still don't see what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/Admin/Cpanel$ /MyApp/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/Admin/(.*)$ /MyApp/$1
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that `Admin/Cpanel/` is just one view. I have many, like `/Admin/Users`, `/Admin/Settings`, `/Admin/Account`, etc. But I also have static files in actual folders, like `/MyApp/css/`, `/MyApp/js/`, `/MyApp/images/`, etc. So when the static file exists it should not rewrite to `index.php`